# rails error on not existing line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I have an file named weekly_report_message.rb with 26 lines of code

```
module MessageTypes
  class WeeklyReportMessage

    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps

    field :last_week_date, type: DateTime
    field :this_week_date, type: DateTime
    field :runs, type: Integer
    field :runs_completed, type: Integer
    field :distance, type: Float
    field :distance_completed, type: Float
    has_one :message

    def basic_info
      {
        :last_week_date => !last_week_date.blank? ? last_week_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") : "",
        :this_week_date => !this_week_date.blank? ? this_week_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") : "",
        :runs => runs,
        :runs_completed => runs_completed,
        :distance => distance.round(1),
        :distance_completed => distance_completed.round(1)
      }
    end
  end
end
```

this code works ok on local machine and on production server in some cases but there one case in which basic_info method is called and this call results in error (only on production) which says:

```
undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass
app/models/message_types/weekly_report_message.rb:30:in `basic_info'
```

but I dont' have 30 lines in this file, the code was deployed, I checked with cat the code on server and is the same as on local, no matter what changes I make in this file it still give me this error, I restarted nginx but still have this error

Comment: Do the logs tell you anything about where and on what object is the method basic_info called?

Comment: it's called in another 2 methods like this weekly_report_message.try(:basic_info)